# Pyspark: GroupBy Max value and show ID

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe in Pyspark

```
+---+-----+----------+
| id|month|units_sold|
+---+-----+----------+
|  1|   02|       325|
|  2|   02|       145|
|  3|   02|       489|
|  1|   03|       247|
|  2|   03|       741|
|  3|   03|       403|
+---+-----+----------+
```

I need to groupby this dataset by month, aggregate the units by max and show the ID with the max value.

I tried grouping the data, but can't show the ID:

```
df.groupby('month').agg(F.max('units_sold'))
```

I need the following result:

```
+-----+---+---------------+
|month| id|max(units_sold)|
+-----+---+---------------+
|   02|  3|            489|
|   03|  2|            741|
+-----+---+---------------+
```

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula I am using Databricks

Comment: Function "row_number" over Window can be used, example: https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-find-maximum-row-per-group-in-dataframe/

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below code and it works for me with your input dataframe:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df=spark.createDataFrame([[1,2,325],[2,2,145],[3,2,489],[1,3,247],[2,3,741],[3,3,403]],schema=['id','month','units_sold'])

from pyspark.sql import Window

w0=Window.partitionBy(col("month")).orderBy(lit("A"))
df=df.withColumn("flag",when(col("units_sold")==max(col("units_sold")).over(w0),1).otherwise(lit(0)))
df=df.sort(['month','flag'])

df2=df.groupby('month').agg(max(col('units_sold')),last(col('id')))
df2.drop(col('flag')).show()
```